# return statement inside a for loop calls the function being defined

Tags: python, stack

I stumbled upon this snippet and it's got me scratching my head because it uses a `return` statement that calls the function that is being defined.

The function reverses the substrings contained within parentheses. For example, the string `"foo(oof(bar))"` is expected to return `"foobarfoo"`.

```py
def solution(string):
    for i, v in enumerate(string):
        if string[i] == "(":
            start = i
        if string[i] == ")":
            end = i
            return solution(string[:start] + string[start+1:end][::-1] + string[end+1:])
    return string
```

I am confused by the use of the first `return`. I understand it cannot be replaced by `string =`  because it would break the iterative dynamic.

However, why does `return` loop through the function until it ends instead of breaking out of the loop?

Comment: It's a _recursive function_. It keeps calling itself until it reaches the base case string[i] == "("

Comment: It does break out of the loop. But first it calls the `solution()` function again. It returns after the recursive call returns.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know how to look this up bc I wasn't aware of this kind of function.

Comment: BTW, it's not "being defined": the interpreter it's going to read the full definition and, if it's syntactically correct, it's going to apply it the way it is.

Comment: Even with not knowing the term, searching "function that calls itself" works in google and uncovers the term.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why they use enumerate, then proceed to use the index in the string itself. Enumerate does this for you ie:
in this case sting[i] = v.

```
def solution(string):
    for i, v in enumerate(string):
        if v == "(":
            start = i
        if v == ")":
            end = i
            return solution(string[:start] + string[start+1:end][::-1] + string[end+1:])
    return string
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).